# how to query the key exists in mongoid or mongo(ruby)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ee9e17e88adc3a1d6c2a39f"},"title":"test","products":{"car":"yes hello"}}
```

how can I query the documents which have the key car use mongo _id or mongo?
I tried

```
    irb(main):042:0> x = client[:materials].find({"products.car":{$exists=>true}})
=> #<Mongo::Collection::View:0x47269370736460 namespace='db.materials' @filter={"products.car"=>{nil=>true}} @options={}>
irb(main):043:0> x.count
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):43
BSON::InvalidKey (NilClass instances are not allowed as keys in a BSON document.)
```

and I don't know how to do it with mongo _id or mongo. and puzzled about the error message

Answer (score 1):

You do need to quote the $exists, but you also are not using the right search method. The method .find expects a document id, but you are passing it a query string.

If you only want the first record that matches your query, use:

```
.find_by("products.car":{"$exists"=>true})
```

If you want all records that match your query, use:

```
.where("products.car":{"$exists"=>true})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{$exists=>true}
```

This references the global variable `$exists`. Try:

```
{"$exists"=>true}
```